# Regex match last space before a digit on each new line

Tags: regex

Here is an example of data that I have:

```
Allt Uisg an t-Sidhein,Highland 57.22N 04.29W NH613171
Alltwalis,Sir Gaerfyrddin (Carmarthenshire) 51.95N 04.27W SN4431
Alltwen,Castell-nedd Phort Talbot (Neath Port Talbot) 51.71N 03.85W SN7203
Allt-yr-yn,Casnewydd (Newport) 51.58N 03.02W ST2988
```

I have 44000 rows of this data (All towns in UK).
I want to format it in a CSV format, so that I could import it into a database.

This is how the example data should look once formatted (data items separated with commas):

```
Allt Uisg an t-Sidhein,Highland,57.22N,04.29W,NH613171
Alltwalis,Sir Gaerfyrddin (Carmarthenshire),51.95N,04.27W,SN4431
Alltwen,Castell-nedd Phort Talbot (Neath Port Talbot),51.71N,03.85W,SN7203
Allt-yr-yn,Casnewydd (Newport),51.58N,03.02W,ST2988
```

So now I need to come up with a regular expression that would match each space just before the first number (the North coordinate) on all lines, so that I could then replace it with a comma.

Any info or help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which language are you running?

Comment: `/ (\w+) (\w+) (\w+)$/` would match the last three elements of a string that are separated by spaces, and allow for backreferences so that (depending on what language you're using) you can do something like `string.replace(/ (\w+) (\w+) (\w+)$/g,',\1,\2,\3')`

Comment: If you want to match each space before the North coordinate and replace it with a comma then why do you have the space replaced with a comma before the West coordinates and SN... as well?

Comment: I am running PHP, but I will do the replacement manually in Sublime Text 2 which support regex for search and replace.

Comment: @hwnd Because that's the end goal. However my main concern is to get that space before the first coordinate. Other ones I can figure out how to do.

Comment: `preg_replace('/ (\S+) (\S+) (\S+)$/', ',$1,$2,$3', string);` will do what you're looking for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a **Positive Lookahead** here, this works for the data you provided:

In Sublime Text 2: Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> to open the **Search and Replace**, enable *Regular Expression*.

```
Find What:  +(?=\d+\.\d+[NSEW]|[A-Z]{2}\d{4,})
Replace With: ,
```

[Live Demo](http://regex101.com/r/sV2vS7/2)

Comment: Thanks, this is great!
Though sublime is taking ages trying to replace all those 100k of spaces :D

Comment: @alwaysStuck Glad I could help, not sure if notepad++ would be faster but you could try with that as well.

Comment: I noticed that it didn't replace all instances fully. For example this line has one space left after the N: 
Beult,Kent,51.21N 00.44E,TQ708489
Do you know what could cause this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex for finding:

```
\s+(?=\d+\.\d+[NW]|[A-Z]{2}\d+)
```

#### [Regx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/eY2mX0/1)

Replace this match with comma.

Answer (score 1):

Use some capture groups like so:

```
(.+) (\d{2}\.\d{2}[NS]) (\d{2}\.\d{2}[EW]) ([A-Z]{2}\d{4,})
```

Then you can format it however you want (in your case with commas):

```
$1,$2,$3,$4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:
`(?=\d{2}\.\d{2}[NEWS])| (?=[A-Z]{2}\d+)`
(with a space in the beginning)

Answer (score 1):

I would do this:

```
import re
l = "Allt Uisg an t-Sidhein,Highland 57.22N 04.29W NH613171"
re.sub(".(\s)[0-9]", ",", l, 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

And the goodnews is **sublimetext2** support `\K` option,

**Pattern:**

```
.*\K (\S+) (\S+) (\S+)$
```

**Replacement:**

```
,\1,\2,\3
```

It replaces space before the last three words with `,`

**Before:**

[image]

**After:**

[image]

Comment: i had done the replacement operation, so that the pic shows like that.